# Graphcms file upload 400 bad request

Tags: graphql

I am attempting to upload a file using graphcms and the documentation provided here:
https://graphcms.com/docs/content-api/assets

This is my handle submit function for the time being. I am just trying to log the response:

```
async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const response = await fetch(`${process.env.GRAPHQL_URL_ENDPOINT}/upload`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.BEARER_TOKEN}`,
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            body: `fileUpload=${fileUpload.files[0]}`,
          });
        
          console.log(response);
      }
```

I have confirmed that `fileUpload.files[0]` is a file object. I am getting this response:
`Response { type: "cors", url: "https://api-us-west-2.graphcms.com/v2/cklvg9qoslthv01xi4wou54sk/master/upload", redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, statusText: "Bad Request", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }`

Comment: check network request format ... search for proper fetch+FormData upload questions/examples

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to append the `file` in `formData` and then pass it within the `body`. Here is a working example

```
const handleUpload = (file: SelectedFile) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("fileUpload", file);
    fetch(`GRAPHQL_URL_ENDPOINT/upload`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result: Asset) => {
        console.log("Success:", result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  };
```